# Search Multiple URLs for New Content

Tags: search

I have a group of websites I want to check daily for new content and I'm not sure what the best way is. I'm hoping one of you can help me.

With Google Custom Search, I can search a group of websites -- but what I want is to find *any* content posted in the past 24 hours, not just content related to a specific keyword. I've tried searching with no keyword and I get no results.

With regular Google Search, I can choose a single site (site:www.example.com), use search tools to limit the results to the past 24 hours, enter no keyword and find anything that's new. But that only works for one site at a time, as far as I can tell.

With Google News search, I can find new content from multiple sites -- but that only works for news sources. If I enter nytimes.com, it works; if I enter dcenr.gov.ie/ I get nothing.

Any ideas on another way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [creating a RSS feed](http://page2rss.com/) for the webpages and then using a RSS reader to check for updates.

Comment: I created RSS feeds for about four of the 50 sites I want to monitor and then got a message saying there was a rate limit. Also, I some sites apparently can't be monitored by Page2RSS.

Comment: You can also check (if you haven't done already) if the sites have RSS feeds.

Comment: Most of them don't. I think I'm going to try watchthatpage.com.